# How do I configure NServiceBus NHibernate Persistance to use a table name other than "Subscription"?

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus5

How do I configure NServiceBus NHibernate Persistance to use a table name other than "Subscription"?

I am using NServicebus 5 and SQL Server 2008 for Subscription storage.

I was able to set my schema with the following appSetting